# Unable to resolve Dependency in Installing a Nuget Package

Tags: nuget, .net-framework-version

I have created a NuGet package which I have successfully installed in DotNet Core. But when I try to install the same in my DotNet Framework 6.1 web application I am getting an error message as "Unable to resolve dependencies for my Nuget. Source(s) used nuget.org, Microsoft VisualStudio Packages". Could anyone please provide a solution for me. Is it something related to my .Net Framework Versions.

Comment: Did you make the package in .net core or standard?

Comment: It's just .net standard 2.0

Comment: The actual issue here is like one of my dependencies in my package is showing this error. The package is built-in Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: Your package AND its dependencies need to have assets for both netcore and netfx. If a dependency is not applicable to a TFM, you can condition your dependencies on TFM.